# Can I add project's root .gradle folder to the .gitignore file?

Tags: flutter, gradle, gitignore

Root folder of Flutter project has a .gradle folder. I'd like to stop tracking it and exclude it from the git index. Could you please advice whether I would meet and issues doing this? What is it responsible for? And is it critical if new developers will pull the project without this folder? I couldn't find any docs regarding this. Also I see that this folder isn't excluded by default.

[image: project structure]

Comment: `./android/.gradle` is generated/updated when you build the project (e.g. `flutter run` command). You can ignore it for your repo as it will get recreated on your local machine. I'm not sure about a .gradle at the root of your project or why you have one there. It could serve a completely different purpose for your app.

Comment: @daddygames I meant ./.gradle, not ./android/.gradle

Answer (score 1):

Gradle stores project-specific cache in the `.gradle` folder. You can definitely ignore it without meeting any problem. Even GitHub put it in their gitignore templates: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Gradle.gitignore.

#### Reference

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:project_root

Comment: To be more clear, you should ignore ˋ.gradleˋ